# Unknown process named "wuowoo" running in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, virus, process, malware

Today I am reviewing the system's performance through Task Manager in Windows 7 and I noticed a process named `wuowoo.exe`. I googled it and checked in SuperUser site also but I can't find any information about it. Is it a normal Windows process or does it belongs to some malware?

Update:

I found the file resides inside my user folder as a folder and the folder contains nothing.  I simply deleted it. But still don't know what kind of process it is and what task it performed to my computer.

Comment: Get path `wuowoo.exe`: `Wmic process where (Name='wuowoo.exe') get ProcessId, CommandLine, Description, ExecutablePath`. Get detail `wuowoo.exe`: `wmic PROCESS WHERE ProcessId="<ProcessId Value at previos command>" ASSOC >> processinfo.txt`

Comment: Not much info, PrevX found it in 2010: http://www.prevx.com/filenames/X36200031021172502-X1/WOUWOO.EXE.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never seen a process with that name in any Windows 7 system. What you can do is to start in safe mode (press F8 when the computer is booting), and see if the process is still there. If it is, then it is very likely a process related to some special feature of your Windows 7 setup.

If not, then you can try to run some malware scanners and antivirus, and see if they find anything. Also, you can check msconfig (start | run | msconfig), and check the Startup tab. You can also check the Services tab and hide all non-Microsoft services. See if you see anything suspicious, or something with a similar name to wuowoo.exe.

You can also go to regedit and see if you find something more inside the key: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run`